# PHP: getting in between timestamps data from an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

A php student here that has been stuck for many hours now :(

Here's my problem, this:

```
   echo"<pre>";print_r($array1);echo"</pre>";
```

prints:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 4d6f6aec35993704d52c0d9d
                [createdAt] => 1299147500
                [place] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 4adcda40f964a5208a3e21e3
                    )


            )

                [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 654jk654n646g54j6kl54j645
                [createdAt] => 1299147500
                [place] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 4gh543gh5h5g354h3gg53gh
                    )


            )
.
.
.
```

createdAt is the timestamp of the date the place was created. 
I need the place id of the places created in between timestamps.

Here's my approach on the in between timestamps logic:

```
$array2 = array();

$begin = strtotime("2011-02-17 12:22:49");
$end = strtotime("2011-03-03 10:00:00");

foreach($array1 as $timestamp){
    if($timestamp <= $end && $timestamp >= $begin){
                $array2[] = $timestamp;
    }

}
```

It is correct to me, but as I said the info I need in $array2 is the place ids created in between these timestamps.

How can I do that?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a nice use-case for closures in PHP >= 5.3:

```
$begin = strtotime("2011-02-17 12:22:49");
$end   = strtotime("2011-03-03 10:00:00");

$array2 = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item->place->id;
}, array_filter($array1, function($item) use($begin, $end) {
    return $item->createdAt >= $begin && $item->createdAt <= $end;
}));
```

Essentially it's the same code as shown by [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713964/php-getting-in-between-timestamps-data-from-an-array/5714025#5714025), but instead of the old-style anonymous functions we use the newer closures from PHP 5.3.

Comment: A sight for sore eyes. ;-) Unfortunately I'm still too tied to 5.2 for the moment... :-(

Answer (score 2):

Just trying to be clever here... ;-)

```
$begin = strtotime("2011-02-17 12:22:49");
$end = strtotime("2011-03-03 10:00:00");

$array2 = array_filter($array1, create_function('$o', "return \$o->createdAt >= $begin && \$o->createdAt <= $end;"));
$array2 = array_map(create_function('$o', 'return $o->place->id;'), $array2);
```

Comment: I don't see [place] .. is that the problem?

Comment: @alex Yes we do. :o) @user Sorry, added the place. I guess the reason you're getting an empty array is that neither result is within the given timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this if I understand the question correctly.

```
$array2 = array();

$begin = strtotime("2011-02-17 12:22:49");
$end = strtotime("2011-03-03 10:00:00");

foreach($array1 as $item){
    $timestamp = $item->createdAt;
    if($timestamp <= $end && $timestamp >= $begin){
                $array2[] = $item->place;
    }

}
```

Also just so you know you can do:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($array2, 1) . '</pre>';
```

to save your self some key strokes when debugging.

Comment: Why I'm getting an empty array??